# Robot Framework Installation from Source- Windows 2012

Tags: python, robotframework, windows-server-2012

We have a directory structure as follows:

C:\core\Python

C:\core\RobotFramework

We are trying to create a package using the above directry structure that will allow us to install RobotFramework on a Windows 2012 Server. We want to be able to use the Source Files for both the packages so that we can deploy the same package using a wrapper to instances across the company.

1. Installed Python 3.6.2 x64 bit- This seems to run fine from the directory above after the PATH is set.
2. We installed Robot Framework from the source with these instructions- http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-robot-and-rebot-scripts (Command- python setup.py install --root C:\core\RobotFramework)
3. We tried to run robot --version to validate the installation and received the below error-

   C:\core\Python>robot --version

   C:\IQOQ\CORE\Python\python.exe: **Error while finding module specification for 'robot.run' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot')**

When we look for robot.run file, we were unable to locate that in any of Robot installation files. Has anyone ever seen this?

How do we get robot --version command to work properly so we can validate.

NOTE- We are not using pip install command's as the target servers we will be deploying this package to will NOT have any internet access.

Comment: Did you modify PYTHONPATH to tell python to look in `C:\core` or `C:\core\RobotFramework`?

Comment: Below Python PATH's were set as System Variables- C:\IQOQ\CORE\Python
and C:\IQOQ\CORE\Python\Python36\Scripts

Comment: I don't know what a "Below Python PATH" is, but I'm asking about PYTHONPATH, not PATH. If you set PYTHONPATH as a system variable, you should show what you set it to in your question.

Comment: I dint had the PYTHONPATH variable set earlier. I just added it pointing it to C:\IQOQ\CORE\Python;C:\IQOQ\CORE\Python\python36;C:\IQOQ\CORE\Robot Framework\IQOQ\CORE\Python\Lib
 and tried again. It resulted same error.

Comment: Is `C:\IQOQ\COR‌​E\Robot Framework\IQOQ\CORE\Python\Lib` a copy-and-paste error? It seems to me that the `C:\ ` is missing in front of the `Python\Lib` directory: `C:\IQOQ\COR‌​E\Robot Framework;C:\IQOQ\CORE\Python\Lib`